# Trying to add more than one number (OOP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to add more than 1 to the value of ID but it only adds 1 extra even if I press the button again.

```php
<?php


class Game {

    public $id = 1;

    public function add() {
        $this->id++;
    }
}

$game = new Game;
echo $game->id;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $game->add();
    echo $game->id;
}
?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is stateless. That is, it runs once and then forgets about everything that just happened. Passing values between PHP sessions can be done with session cookies or form input values. Try something like this instead:

```
<?php    
class Game {    
    public $id = 1;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function add() {
        $this->id++;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $the_id = $_POST["id"];
} else {
    $the_id = 1;
}
$game = new Game($the_id);
echo $game->id;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $game->add();
    echo $game->id;
}
?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$game->id?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The value is passed by the form POST to the script. Then the value is passed to the constructor of the object.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. I've tried this and it adds very high random numbers instead of just one for some reason.

Comment: No, it does exactly what it should.

Comment: First page load it will output 1, on post it will output 1 then 2, next post will output 2 then 3, etc.

Comment: Hmm weird, goes up by 101* wasn't random, sorry.